# Rake routes for Java web apps?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm a longtime desktop developer (C/C++) that's been doing web development with Rails since ~2005. I've now been thrust onto a Java web application at work and just do not understand how any developer can grok where all of the URI's are being directed.

I'm working in IntelliJ, and there are six different projects that contribute artifacts to the war. I know that the mappings are defined in web.xml, but it's impossible to tell from there which URI's are directed to which beans or whatever.

As I write this I already have a sinking feeling that there's no answer, but is there some ability to get a straight answer of which routes are exposed by the application and where they point to in source code a la `rake routes`?

**UPDATE**

@Dave: It's a mix of Jersey REST and Icefaces. I only vaguely understand what Icefaces is.

Comment: It depends *entirely* on the web framework, which you neglect to mention. If it's straight servlets, it's right there in the web.xml, and it's a trivial script to line up servlet names to their mappings. If it's a framework, then w/o knowing which, it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an ant script  or some other script anywhere that contains details to how the projects are pulled together and built/packaged into the war?

Ultimately everything is constructed into a base directory containing files, directories and a /WEB-INF directory. /WEB-INF is protected and it's contents are only accessible via URI's via the web.xml. Where everything outside of the /WEB-INF in the root directory is accessible via URI's (relative to the root directory) or URL's.

I'm not completely confident in what is all entitled with a `rake route`, but I believe your sinking feeling is correct - what you see in the web.xml is what you have to work with in java web-apps. The `<servlet-class>` tag maps the package.diectory.to.JavaClass to a given `<servlet-name>` and else where in the deployment descriptor, the is a `<servlet-mapping>` and `<url-pattern>` that maps the given url to a servlet-name.

Comment: Ok- as I mentioned I was afraid there wasn't a silver bullet answer. It may be as much bad implementation as it is lack of tooling in Java apps to answer my particular question (i.e., what URI's are exposed and where to they map to?)